# How can I register a short code using form inputs from users?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to build a plugin where I need to take inputs from users from a form and create a shortcode with some of the user inputs. I have created a separate page for the adding form. there I am trying to process the input data and save on a custom table in WordPress DB. The problem I am facing is that, After saving the data in my custom table, I want to create a shortcode with some of the inputs but the add_shortcode method with its callback function is not working. I am new to Wordpress so I am not sure where I am going wrong.

I have tried a lot of ways but at the end was left with scratching my head. I have tried first saving everything. Then on the plugin main file. Tried to retrieve data from DB and create shortcode there. But no result

```
if (isset($_POST['sc_add_submit'])) {

$name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['sc_name']);
$shortcode = sanitize_text_field($_POST['shortcode']);
$content = sanitize_text_field($_POST['content']);
$short_desc = sanitize_text_field($_POST['short_desc']);

$errors = [];
$msgs = [];



global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert('wp_sc_content', array(
    'sc_name' => $name,
    'shortcode' => 'sc_'.$shortcode,
    'content' => $content,
    'short_desc' => $short_desc,
));
$sc_lastInsert_id = $wpdb->insert_id;

if (!empty($sc_lastInsert_id)) {
    $msgs[] = "Shortcode inserted succesfully";
    function sc_register_shortcode()
    {

        return $content;
    }
    add_shortcode($shortcode, 'sc_register_shortcode');


} else {
    $errors[] = "DB insert failed";
}
}
```

I just need to register the shortcode each time the form is submitted. So that the user paste the shortcode and it returns the content wherever he wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your shortcodes are "added" as soon as the form is submitted. When you navigate to other pages or reload the screen, the `add_shortcode()` is not triggering anymore!

What you need to do is to query your shortcodes from the database and hook it to something like `init`, so it's always loaded.

Let me write the code for you-

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_54302608_add_shortocodes' );
function wpse_54302608_add_shortocodes() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table = 'wp_sc_content'; // hopefully $wpdb->prefix . 'sc_content';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM {$table}";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $query );

    foreach ( $results as $row ) {
        $fn = function() use ( $row ) {
            return $row->content;
        };
        add_shortcode( $row->shortcode, $fn );
    }
}
```

Not tested. But should work.

Comment: where should I write the function. In my main plugin file or the file where the form is situated ?

Comment: thanks @mukto90. This works fine for me. Can you please tell me if I now edit the content will it update accordingly?